# printing Timedelta to nanosecond precision

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, output, timedelta

How can one print directly pandas Timedelta with nanosecond precision? For now, my solution is to add to Timedelta some dummy date to be able to do it. Hopefully, there is a better solution.

```py
import pandas as pd
time = pd.Timedelta(50400001747113)
print(time)
#     0 days 14:00:00.001747
print(pd.Timestamp('2019-10-02') + time)
# 2019-10-02 14:00:00.001747113
```

You can see that Timestamp is printed up to nanoseconds while Timedelta only to microseconds.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.Timedelta.components` is `NamedTuple-like`. Make a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and pass the Components as a dict.

```
>>> t
Timedelta('0 days 14:00:00.001747')
>>> fmt = '{days:} days {hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}.{milliseconds:03}{microseconds:03}{nanoseconds:03}'
>>> fmt.format(**t.components._asdict())
'0 days 14:00:00.001747113'
>>>
```

---

Or as you can see in [the source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timedeltas.pyx#L1098), the `_repr_base` method has a format parameter that you could use.

```
>>> t._repr_base('all')
'0 days 14:00:00.001747113'
```

---

You could also subclass the Pandas.Timedelta and override the `**str** method.

```
class MyTD(pd.Timedelta):
    def __str__(self):
        return self._repr_base(format='all')

>>> t = MyTD(50400001747113)
>>> print(t)
0 days 14:00:00.001747113
```

---

Given that the single underscore prefix for `_repr_base` may indicate that it is an implementation detail that could change and `pd.Timedelta.components` only is `NamedTuple`**-like** (whatever that means - does it guarantee a NamedTuple interface?) you could be safe and extract the values from `.components` and pass them to a format string.

```
import operator

>>> components = operator.attrgetter('days','hours','minutes','seconds','milliseconds','microseconds','nanoseconds')
>>> fmt = '{} days {:02}:{:02}:{:02}.{:03}{:03}{:03}'
>>> 
>>> t
Timedelta('0 days 14:00:00.001747')
>>> print(fmt.format(*components(t.components)))
0 days 14:00:00.001747113
>>>
```

That may be being paranoid but I couldn't find any info along those lines. Maybe someone will chime in.

Comment: Thank you! That is almost what I need. To make it default, one could do `pd.Timedelta.__str__ = lambda x: x._repr_base('all')`

Answer (score 1):

Probably nanoseconds are just not printed, but they are there:

```
time = pd.Timedelta(50400001747113, unit='ns')
attrs = 'days,seconds,microseconds,nanoseconds'.split(',')
values = [getattr(time, a) for a in attrs]
print(dict(zip(attrs, values)))
```

Prints:

```
{'days': 0, 'seconds': 50400, 'microseconds': 1747, 'nanoseconds': 113}
```

You can easily access nanoseconds via attribute:

```
>>> time.nanoseconds
113
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I know that the nanoseconds are there. My question is how one can force them to be printed. One solution being `pd.Timedelta.__repr__ = lambda x: str(pd.Timestamp('2019-10-02') + time)[11:]; print(time)` (assuming that time is <24h).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the attributes that you want via [named tuple like object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html):

```
import pandas as pd
time = pd.Timedelta(50400001747113)
>>> time.components
Components(days=0, hours=14, minutes=0, seconds=0, milliseconds=1, microseconds=747, nanoseconds=113)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are pre pandas 1.5.0 and dont mind this getting deprecated, you can just call td.delta to get the time in nanoseconds
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.delta.html